# How to use Redux inside a React Router stateless middleware?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

When some user try to access any page of my application, a React Router middleware is called to check if the user is logged in. The problem is that to access the Redux store I need to use `store.getState()` and if I use `store.listen(...)` I receive an error (`'component' doesn't exist`).

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => { // Receive component and path
  return (
    <Route { ...rest } render={(props) => {
        return store.getState().login.token.status === 200
          ? <Component { ...props } />
          : <Redirect to="/login" />
       }}
    />
  )
}

// store.subscribe(PrivateRoute) // Error when some page is requested

export default PrivateRoute;
```

I know that to listen changes on this function I need to pass a component, but I think it's not possible because it's a middleware. Do I really need to listen for changes in this case, if yes, how can I do this (how to mock this type of thing) ?

**Obs** : Example `<PrivateRoute path="/private" component={() => <h1>Private</h1>}/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, hasLogin, ...rest }) => (
 <Route
  {...rest}
  render={props => (
    hasLogin ? (
      <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: '/login'
        }}
      />
    )
  )}
/>
)
export default connect(state => ({
 hasLogin: state.login.hasLogin
}))(PrivateRoute)
```

In the switch call like this

```
<PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={some page} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Redux

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth: auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      )
    }
  />
);

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Answer (score 0):

After login have you dispatch an action to store the the login values in store.
if yes check that.

and i think you can store the login token in `localStorage` [read about WebStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and easily get it back using `store.get('keyname')`.

Comment: [What’s the best way to store tokens in Redux ?](https://michaelwashburnjr.com/best-way-to-store-tokens-redux/)